# Output not visible jstl c:out not showing on browser

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jstl

Problem: When I open page view source this data is shown on browser

```
 Hello there jsp

        <c:forEach var="student" items="2abcnullmca">
                        <c:out value= ""/>
                    </c:forEach>

                    <c:out value= "abc" />
```

And on browser it does not show c:out value in spring I have used `model.addAttribute()` to show data

Comment: You have to and jstl jar file to your classpath or add dependency to your pox.xml

Comment: Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

Actually I forgot to include jstl tag thanks for looking into it but.
Here is the Tag  -

```
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```